# Zend_Db problem whith the placeholders from SQL string

Tags: zend-db, placeholder

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT i_id AS "entity_id", "entity_1" AS "type"
FROM tbl_extensions WHERE ext = 50
```

which returns me the result and an additional column "type" with the value "entity_1"

to gain the same with Zend_Db I've tried:

```
$db->fetchAll($db->select()
                 ->from('tbl_extensions',
                         array('entity_id' => 'i_id',
                               'type' => 'entity_1'))
                    ->where('ext = ?', 50)));
```

But I have the following error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tbl_extensions.type' in 'field list'

It looks like Zend tries to find a column instead of creating it within the result.

Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest solution would be to use `Zend_Db_Expr`.

```
$db->fetchAll($db->select()
    ->from('tbl_extensions',
        array(
            'entity_id' => 'i_id',
            new Zend_Db_Expr('"entity_1" AS "type"'),
        )
    )
    ->where('ext = ?', 50));
```